# Extracting Link and Content from PDF in C# VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, pdf-extraction

I'm a little bit lost with PDF standards for data extraction.
I'm using iText and looking for extraction of clickable HTML link within a PDF + Text that contains those links.

I achieved to get HTML links, but how can I get text from those links ?

```
   public static List<string> linkCollector(string pdfPath)
    {
        List<string> linkCollection = new List<string>();
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
        {
            var pageDict = pdfDoc.GetPage(page);
            var annotList =  pageDict.GetAnnotations();

            for (int i=0;i< annotList.Count(); i++)
            {
                PdfObject B = annotList[i].GetPdfObject();
                var annotDict = B as PdfDictionary;
                var linkDict = (PdfDictionary)annotDict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.A);
                var sUri = linkDict.Get(PdfName.URI).ToString();
                
                linkCollection.Add(sUri);
            }

        }
        return linkCollection;
    }
```

Comment: I suppose the questions is not related to VSTO at all. So, I remove the VSTO tag from the post.

Comment: thanks, indeed i use VSTO but this is not the main topic here

Comment: The task is common for all .net based applications I think.

Comment: That's right. Anybody knows how to help here ?